# How to grab what command line parameters are being sent to cl.exe in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compilation, cl.exe

So I'm trying to figure out what command line arguments are being sent to cl.exe in Visual Studio 2013 when you build a project.

I need this for a side-project that just uses the actual cl.exe and send in parameters via a text file.

For example:

```
/Zc:wchar_t /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_LIB" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /EHsc /Od /MT *.cpp kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /link /FORCE:MULTIPLE /OUT:Output.exe
```

is in the text file to use for cl.exe.

However compiling the program using cl.exe only works barely half of the time. The program will either lock up or crash.

Compiling the program in Visual Studio with F7 (Build) works 100% of the time, so the only thing I can think of why it doesn't work and crash on cl.exe is because I have the wrong parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to get the command line from the project property page:

1. In the C/C++ section there is a "Command Line" subsection that lists the command line that will be used (without the file name parameter).
2. In the C/C++ section in the General Subsection, change "Suppress Startup Banner" to "No". This will then print the command line used for each source file in the output window when you build.